# How can I transform the X and Y values obtained via PointerCommandArgs into a Yaxes (AXIS) value?

Tags: avaloniaui, livecharts

How can I transform the X and Y values obtained via PointerCommandArgs into a Yaxes (AXIS) value?

File: Chart.axaml

`<lvc:CartesianChart PointerPressedCommand="{Binding Click_OnMain_Chart}" Series="{Binding Series}" XAxes="{Binding XAxes}" Sections="{Binding Sections}" YAxes="{Binding YAxes}" />`

File: ChartViewModel.cs

```
public int x {get; set;}
public int y {get; set;}

private void OnPoint_MainChart(PointerCommandArgs point)
{
  x = Int32.Parse(point.PointerPosition.X.ToString());
  y = Int32.Parse(point.PointerPosition.Y.ToString()); 
}
```

I didn't find a way to get Yaxes value.

Livecharts for Avalonia UI.